# How to integrate accept payment type Paynow Stripe on PHP

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

Currently i'm learning about Stripe payment and focus on accept payment use Paynow stripe in PHP from this doc [PAYNOW](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/paynow/accept-a-payment). i'm using laravel to implement stripe on it. but i stuck to display the Paynow QRCode. here is my code

code on view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Accept a payment</title>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
  
    <form id="payment-form" >
    <input id="payment-name" type="text">
    <button   data-secret="{{$client_id}}">Submit Payment</button>
    </form> 
  
  <script>

    var stripe = Stripe('my_secret_key');

    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Set the clientSecret here you got in Step 2
        stripe.confirmPayNowPayment(
            clientSecret,
        ).then((res) => {
            if(res.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
            // The user scanned the QR code
            } else {
            // The user closed the modal, cancelling payment
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is a code on my controller

```
 public function payment_paynow()
  {
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('my_secret_key');

    $response = $stripe->paymentIntents->create(
      [
        'payment_method_types' => ['paynow'],
        'payment_method_data' => ['type' => 'paynow'],
        'amount' => 1099,
        'currency' => 'sgd',
      ]
    );
    
    return view('stripe-paynow', [
      'client_id' => $response->client_secret
    ]);
  }
```

this code couldn't display the QR Code Paynow. Please help how to display it.

Comment: What happens when your page calls `confirmPayNowPayment`?